# Android assets folder pdf path

Tags: android, file, pdf, path, assets

My assets folder : [image]

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MyPdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PDF FILE PATH");
startActivity(intent);`

How do I get path?

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class); intent.putExtra(MyPdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "file:///android_asset/xy.pdf"); startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/about.pdf");
 Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I use your code,but it alert 'invalid file path',why?

Comment: It is invalid because assets are not files by the time the apk gets to the device.